# One basis of extension field works for all roots of minimum polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $p(x)$ be a minimum polynomial of $c \in K \supset F$ over $F[x]$. Say $p(x)$ has multiple distinct roots $\{r_i\}$including $c$. I know that $F(c) \cong F(r_i)$ for each $i$, but is a basis of $F(c)$ literally a basis of each $F(r_i)$?

I am asking this because I have a problem that asks for a basis of an extension field $F(d)$ where $d$ is very complicated and the minimum polynomial of $d$ with degree $n$ is given. However, there is another root $e \neq d$ that has a nicer form. Will the basis $\{1,...,e^{n-1}\}$ be a basis for $F(d)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. For example, $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\cong\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2\,w)\;$ , with $\;w=e^{2\pi i/3}\;$ , since both elements are roots of the irreducible rational polynomial $\;x^3-2\;$, yet the former is a real field whereas the latter is a complex one.

I'm not sure what the multiplicity of the roots has to do here, except the fact that the fields must be of positive characteristic and rather messy imo, as finite extensions of finite fields or of fields of characteristic zero don't contain elements whose minimal polynomials have multiple roots

Answer (score 2):

As Joanpemo answered, not in general. But, if you have that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the same irreducible polynomial, then $F(\alpha)\cong F(\beta)$ with isomorphism $1\mapsto 1,\ \alpha\mapsto \beta$ which clearly sends base $\{1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ to base $\{1,\beta,\ldots,\beta^{n-1}\}$, so you can do all the necessary calculations with one base, and pull it back to the original field via the isomorphism.